# Join using associatif table

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I set up a relationship between the following three tables : Card, Event and Presence (associatif table). Presence my associatif table, which contains id_card and id_event. I tried to create a fuction that return $count (number of event foreach member).
But my problem is $count return if the number of all event or zero and the result have been 1 
My controller :

```
$count = DB::table('presences')
  ->join('cards','cards.id','presences.id_card')
  ->join('events','events.id','presences.id_event')
  ->where('presences.date','like','%event.dateEvent%')
  ->where('presences.qrcode','like','%cards.qrcode_membre%')
  ->get()
  ->count();
```

Model Card :

```
     public function event()
        {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event');
        }
```

Migration :

```
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('nom');
        $table->string('prenom');
        $table->string('cin');
        $table->date('dateNaissance');
        $table->date('dateAffection');
        $table->string('qrcode_membre')
```

Model Event :

```
     public function card()
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Card');
    }
```

Migration :

```
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('libelle');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->date('dateEvent');
```

Model Presence :

```
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->date('heureEntree');
        $table->date('heureSortir');
        $table->date('date');
        $table->string('qrcode');
        $table->unsignedInteger('id_card');
        $table->foreign('id_card')->references('id')->on('cards');
        $table->unsignedInteger('id_event');
        $table->foreign('id_event')->references('id')->on('events');
```

Comment: Amal, do you have models for `Presence`, `Card`, `Event`?

Comment: @BenjaminBeganović i pasted the rest of code. i did not found the error !